# HTML - Table overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with a table structure in html and need help.

Below table is giving overlapping in IE(see image), however, looks fine in FF. Can anyone please help?

```
<div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Amca cocuklari</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>Battal Turan</tr>
     <tr>Kamil Turan</tr>
     <tr>Tonni Turan</tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>Battal Turan</tr>
     <tr>Kamil Turan</tr>
     <tr>Tonni Turan</tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   .....
   ...
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete example, including all the relevant HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The actual problem was the missing td inside tr.